# isEmpty doesn't appear in suggestions (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

I write to you today because I am developping a code for a quizz application and among the things i want to do is to check if a user fill an empty field text but when i do that in Kotlin : it simply doesn't work and I don't know why. Here is my code :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMV80.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMY9q.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMV80.png)

Could you help please ?

Comment: What error message does it give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `isEmpty()`, like a function call - not a property

Comment: The problem is that even if i put the brackets , it doesn't work

Comment: What version of kotlin are you using?

Comment: I upgraded my version of kotlin and it finally works thanksss